# Compile time errors for incorrect model in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there any way where one can have compile time errors for strongly typed views.  Let's say I have a view in the folder `/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` with the following code & strongly typed Model:

```
@model CSTemplate.Models.Home.HomeIndexModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

and then the controller, located at `/Controllers/HomeController.cs` would return the following code.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<string> s = new List<string>();
            return View(s);
        }

    }
```

As you can see, since the View() accepts an object as a model, the compiler won't complain that the model is invalid and would output a run-time error instead, which is:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'CSTemplate.Models.Home.HomeIndexModel'.
```

Is there any way where I can get compile time errors instead of run time errors in case of such model type mismatch, or is there any workaround for this?

Comment: if you have resharper installed it will notify you if the types dont match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our discussions within this question it seems that there is no suggested workaround for such a scenario.  Since the View takes as a parameter the model of type `object`, then the compiler will not complain if you by mistake pass in a model with a different type than that of the strictly typed model of the View.  Pity since if you need to change the type of the strictly typed model of a View, the compiler will not inform you of such previous inconsistent models being passed over to the view but such errors are only notified during runtime.

Comment: As a thought - would it be possible to have automated tests which attempt to call each action, and fail if there's an error thrown?  It's not a compile error, but if you automatically run the tests after compiling, you'd be able to find it immediately post-compile.

Comment: Yes that would definitely be an option, some form of unit testing on your controller actions in order to make sure they return an acceptable model.

Answer (score 0):

I've uploaded a nuget package to remedy this problem, it generates truly strongly named views.

check it here

https://www.nuget.org/packages/StronglyTypedViews/

Answer (score -1):

`return View(s);` should be returning type of

```
CSTemplate.Models.Home.HomeIndexModel //this is the type model expecting
```

Not

```
List<string> //this is the type you are returning to the model
```

Comment: Yes, that's my question, that the compiler does not complain and restrict building if a View returns something of type `List<string>` instead of the real strictly typed model `CSTemplate.Models.Home.HomeIndexModel`.  The project builds successfully and only gives a runtime error.

Comment: You can pass an anonymous type to a view and compile.

Comment: Yes, my question is to have the compiler complain in case of a model type mismatch with the one strictly typed within the View itself

Comment: I think your case have proven `NOT`. On the other hand what is the point having a strongly typed view if you are passing an anonymous type?

Comment: I think I'm not making myself clear - I am asking the contrary.  I am asking whether there is a way in which the compiler would **complain** of such errors upon build time.  I want that if my View is strongly typed to accept a model of `TypeA`, then the compiler would complain in case I try to provide something of `TypeB`.

Comment: **As far as I know,** compiler does not check what is inside during compilation. Knowing something is passed is enough at the time of compiling (that is why you can pass anonymous types). Real work begins at runtime. At that time it complains about the type mismatch.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, I'm asking whether there is some suggested form of workaround as a solution to my concern above?

Comment: **If you want a compile error,** `return View((CSTemplate.Models.Home.HomeIndexModel)s)`;

Comment: @Kaf This will not give a compile error, but a runtime error.